# How to investigate the cause of an unreachable web server?

Tags: networking, http

I have a very simple problem: http://wikipedia.org does not work on my home network. Yet finding a solution has caused me a headache.

Here are the piece of the puzzle:

- Cable 15Mb/s internet provider
- DLink Wireless home router (DIR-655)
- PC connected with wire
- Laptop connected with wireless
- iPhone connected with wireless (3G cellular data disabled)
- http://wikipedia.org is unreachable (request timeout) on the PC and the Laptop (it timeout when using the ip instead of dns too)
- DnsLookup, ping and tracert works for wikipedia.org
- We are not january 18 (the problem started on february 11)
- Except for wikipedia, every popular sites are reachable
- http://wikipedia.org is reachable from the iPhone <= This really bugs me (3G is disabled, it goes through the router)
- http://wikipedia.org is reachable from the laptop when connected directly to the cable modem
- Restored the router to factory default and updated with latest firmware, the problem is still there

So it look like the problem lies within the router since wikipedia works when connected directly to the cable modem. However, I didn't change anything with the router configuration and a factory reset didn't solve the problem.

How could my router just start blocking http request from a particular server? This seem insane. If anyone have an idea to fix this problem I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears that my IP address was blocked from wikipedia.org. I changed the MAC of the router, this caused an IP renew and it fixed the problem.

Comment: I would accept this answer but the question was migrated from server-fault and used an anonymous account that I can't link to this one.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check... not sure if it has anything to do with it.

- try a different browser / clear cache
- Your HOSTS file. Check out the link below and look at the do it yourself section. Check if there is something wikipedia is rerouting to. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972034

Answer (score 0):

Did you already check your DNS settings?

Maybe you should try [another DNS server](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/speed/public-dns/) from this list.

Enter these adresses in the TCP/IP settings of your workstation/laptop or even the router.

As already said, please have also a look in your hosts files on both clients.